# Neo4j REST API - batch limitations

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing

Is there any limitation to neo4j REST API. I'm creating wrapper that could possible add up to several hundreds items to lucene index via BATCH API. Is there any known limitation to size of batch request?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two limitations: The size of the message payload, and the transaction size on the server, possibly running out of memory. Maybe you could even use the transactional HTTP endpoint? http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-transactional.html

Comment: Transactional endpoint would be ideal but at this point, I'm stuck with server version 1.9 (as much as I know transactional endpoint are introduced @2.0, that's still not stable build)